# Does Spring handle the combination of If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-headers, if-none-match

### Expected behaviour:

`If-None-Match` [has precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) when `If-None-Match` is used in combination with `If-Modified-Since`.

The function `checkNotModified` in `org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest` even references the expected order of precedence with the following comment:

```
// Evaluate conditions in order of precedence.
// See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-6
```

### Observed behaviour

The response is updated with status `NOT MODIFIED` when `checkNotModified` is called from `handleRequest` in `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler` when`lastModifiedTimestamp` indicates that the resources is not modified.

The response *is not* updated again when `checkNotModified` is called from `updateResponse` in `org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` with an etag value indicating that the resource *is* modified.

As a result, the server returns `304 NOT MODIFIED` for an invalid etag when both the `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since`-header is set.

### Problem

After rollback to an earlier deployment, clients will send a lastModifiedTimestamp newer than the content on the server and an invalid etag. Since `If-None-Match` doesn't have precedence as expected, the client recieves a `304 NOT MODIFIED` when a `200 OK` was expected.

### Work-around

Problem can be mitigated by not using `If-Modified-Since`. E.g. utilizing `setUseLastModified(false)` on a resource handler.

### Reproduction

Send a `GET`-request with an invalid etag and `lastModifiedTimestamp` in the future.

### Question

Does Spring handle the combination of `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` correctly, or could this be a bug?

### Update 1

(Thanks [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395796/kevin-christopher-henry))

<s>It seems to be something wrong on my end, since the implementation details locally and in the spring-project differs.</s>

- I mismatched the main and 5.3.x branch. The local implementation matches the implementation on the [5.3.x branch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequest.java).

### Update 2

`checkNotModified` is covered by the test [`IfNoneMatchAndIfNotModifiedSinceShouldNotMatchWhenDifferentETag`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e53c7ae6f5840accbabbb211ae60ab1c05ca396f/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequestHttpMethodsTests.java#L269). However, this test covers the case where `checkNotModified` is called with *both* `eTag` and `lastModifiedTimestamp`. In the case described, `checkNotModified` is called sequentially by overloaded methods. The overloaded method call with `lastModifiedTimestamp` alters the response status to `304 Not Modified`. This does not seem to be handled by the ShallowEtagHeaderFilter where [isEligbleForEtag](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/711820ec708c866d72c92142ba17e6ffe1fa7f44/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java#L152) returns false if the status code is `304`, and the call to `checkNotModified` from [updateResponse in shallowEtagHeaderFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/711820ec708c866d72c92142ba17e6ffe1fa7f44/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java#L125) does not update the response from `304` to `200 OK` if the etag has changed.

### Update 3

[Bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29031)

### Update 4

I've added a simple reproducer [here](https://github.com/skjelmo/spring-unexpected-304).
It's a clean Spring starter with the Spring Web dependency, a HTML file and the shallow etag filter enabled.

Opening http://localhost:8080/index.html should provide necessary values from `ETag` and `Last-Modified` in the response headers.

##### Expected behaviour

Sending a curl request with the `ETag` value set as `If-None-Match`, and `Last-Modified` set as `If-Modified-Since` returns `304 Not Modified` as expected.

If you modify `If-Modified-Since` to be back in time, you receive a `200 OK` as expected.

#### Unexpected behaviour

However, if you only modify the `ETag` value, meaning that the ETag of the cached content differs from the ETag calculated on the server, you expect to get `200 OK`. But, you get a `304 Not Modified` which is unexpected since `If-None-Match` [has precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) when `If-None-Match` is used in combination with `If-Modified-Since`. The precedence is documented in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-6 referenced in [checkNotModified](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/711820ec708c866d72c92142ba17e6ffe1fa7f44/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequest.java#L217) and seemingly obsoleted by https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-13.2.2.

##### Curl

(Remember to replace header values)

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/index.html' \
--header 'If-None-Match: "0c01d44fcb5bdfc18313ea8cb309217af"' \
--header 'If-Modified-Since: Sat, 27 Aug 2022 23:26:55 GMT'
```

##### Problem

The core problem seems to be that [`checkNotModified` in `org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/711820ec708c866d72c92142ba17e6ffe1fa7f44/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java#L125) is called before [the response is updated with status `NOT MODIFIED`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/711820ec708c866d72c92142ba17e6ffe1fa7f44/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequest.java#L236) when [`checkNotModified` is called from `handleRequest` in `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/711820ec708c866d72c92142ba17e6ffe1fa7f44/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java#L574).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing has already been [reported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18798) and supposedly fixed. They also have a test case meant to capture the exact situation you describe (no `ETag` match and future last modified should return `200`): [`IfNoneMatchAndIfNotModifiedSinceShouldNotMatchWhenDifferentETag`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e53c7ae6f5840accbabbb211ae60ab1c05ca396f/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequestHttpMethodsTests.java#L269).

However, as you say, `handleRequest` does not actually call `checkNotModified` with both arguments. And you're seeing this behavior on a current version of the software.

So it sounds like a real bug, and I would say the next step is to file a bug report with Spring Framework.

Comment: I'll dig into that test and see if it actually captures the described situation, or if I can write a test that does. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Also, we've recently updated to Spring 5.3.21.

Comment: [`IfNoneMatchAndIfNotModifiedSinceShouldNotMatchWhenDifferentETag`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e53c7ae6f5840accbabbb211ae60ab1c05ca396f/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequestHttpMethodsTests.java#L269) does not seem to cover the situation, because the tested`checkNotModified` is called sequentially by overloaded methods in the described situation, where the first call without the etag alters the status of the response.

Comment: @Kaffekoppen: I see what you mean, and if you're getting this behavior with a current version then it does sound like a real bug. I've updated the answer. I think the next to step is to file a bug report with the Spring Framework. If a resolution comes from that, please report back here.

Comment: Created [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29031) in the spring-framework repository